# Swift - Getting PDF data working in Simulator but not on a real iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit

I have a really simple app with a button that opens the files app and prints the content of a PDF in the console. This perfectly works on the simulator, but when using the app in a real iOS device, the app won't print anything.

```swift
import PDFKit

 @State var openFile = false

  Button(action:{
                openFile.toggle()
            }){
                
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
            }
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile,
                      allowedContentTypes: [.pdf],
                      onCompletion: {result in
                        if let fileURL = try? result.get() {
                            print(fileURL)
                            if let pdf = PDFDocument(url: fileURL) {
                                print(pdf)
                                let pageCount = pdf.pageCount
                                print(pdf.pageCount)
                                let documentContent = NSMutableAttributedString()

                                for i in 0 ..< pageCount {
                                    guard let page = pdf.page(at: i) else { continue }
                                    guard let pageContent = page.attributedString else { continue }
                                    documentContent.append(pageContent)
                                }
                               
                                print(documentContent.string)
                            }
                            
                        }
                      })
```

In the `Info.plist` I already added the Keys `Supports opening documents in place` and `Application supports iTunes file sharing`, but I just can't find anything to make it work in a real device.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Hey LeonardoXUI, can you print out your fileURL? might be a problem there.

Comment: Hi, Josh, the fileURL is printed correctly, so the problem isn't there. I can confirm that the problem starts at the line ```if let pdf = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)```. Still don't know what's causing it not to work. It works on the simulator.

Comment: I think your PDFDocument init might be failing to produce a proper pdf object. Can you add the PDFDocument init's code to your question?

Comment: I currently don't have an initializer since the tutorial I followed didn't use one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer!

Changed the `if let` to `guard let`
Added `fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` and `fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`

```swift
 Button(action:{
                openFile.toggle()

                
            }){
                
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
            }
        }.fileImporter(
            isPresented: $openFile,
            allowedContentTypes: [.pdf],
            allowsMultipleSelection: false
        ) { result in
            do {

                guard let fileURL: URL = try result.get().first else { return print("error fileURL") }
                fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                guard let pdf = PDFDocument.init(url: fileURL) else {return print("error pdf")}
                let pageCount = pdf.pageCount
                let documentContent = NSMutableAttributedString()
                
                for i in 0..<pageCount {
                    guard let page = pdf.page(at: i) else { continue }
                    guard let pageContent = page.attributedString else { continue }
                    documentContent.append(pageContent)
                }
                fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                print(documentContent.string)
               
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```